# Convert from codepage 1252 (ANSI) to codepage gb2312 (chinese simplified) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to convert my ansi (latin) column to gb2312 (chinese) in sql. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First dump the content of that column to a file (.csv) for example
- Alter the column to use one of the simplified Chinese collations (see MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx))
- Re-import your column from the file

Cannot be more specific without having your table definition.

Comment: Is there a sql convert cast function I can use?  My char column looks like this (ÔÝÍ£)°²»Õ»ªÈÊÉúÎï¼¼ÊõÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾ . It comes from a table that is stored in a datbase with Latin collation.